# Search for a particular column name from with a XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

Just wanted to get some help here. I have a situation where I need to find some data from within the `<Column Name>` tag as shown in the XML below.

I had a issue where some badly formatted data was exported in the system, I found that piece but now there is a process where I IMPORT data out of the system. Now I have a table which contains XML stored.

I have to iterate through the whole table to see if that column name exists in that particular ID column and if it does I will return the ID. Say for example my table name is `Sample` and the columns are (`ID`, `ImportXML`).

Any help on how I can achieve this ? New to dealing with XML from within SQL Server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<ExportConfiguration id="SampleExport">   
    <definitions>    
        <ClientName Value="Sample"/>    
        <FileType Value="XML"/>    
        <FileName>     
            <Value Value="SomeValue"/>      
        </FileName>
        <Columns> 
            <Column Name="abc" DataType="String" Value="test123"/>     
            <Column Name="findthis" DataType="String" Value="Test456"/>         
        </Columns> 
    </definitions>
</ExportConfiguration>
```

So basically from the above mentioned code I want to get the value from within `<Columns>/<Column Name> = "findthis"` so basically `findthis` is my keyword and I want to get all the ID's of the columns which contain the keyword `findthis` just for argument sake.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
-- Test table. 
declare @xTable table (ID int identity(1,1) primary key clustered, XMLData xml)

-- Insert an XML document. I only did one, but the same would work for multiple
insert into @xTable
select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
            <ExportConfiguration id="SampleExport">   
                <definitions>    
                    <ClientName Value="Sample"/>    
                    <FileType Value="XML"/>    
                    <FileName>     
                        <Value Value="SomeValue"/>      
                    </FileName>
                    <Columns> 
                        <Column Name="abc" DataType="String" Value="test123"/>     
                        <Column Name="findthis" DataType="String" Value="Test456"/>         
                    </Columns> 
                </definitions>
            </ExportConfiguration>'

-- Return everything from the table with your XML where there is an attribute at the path "/ExportConfiguration/definitions/Columns/Column" with the name "Name" and the value "findthis"
select *
from @xTable
where XMLData.exist('/ExportConfiguration/definitions/Columns/Column[@Name eq "findthis"]') = 1
```

Comment: Good answer! Just as an enhancement: The search string `"findthis"` may be introduced via `sql:variable()` or `sql:column()` if this is not the same in all cases...